# CSS mask in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css, mask, internet-explorer-10

I need to get the effect of `-webkit-mask-image` in Internet Explorer 10.
Unfortunately, the only way I found with google is putting all the contents into an SVG, which is not applicable.

Answer (score 5):

Experimental masking features in Webkit browsers are just that, experimental. Until they gain more wide-spread adoption, or are officially adopted by the W3C, we shouldn't expect to see other browsers implement the same feature.

Consider an alternative solution. For instance, Martin Beeby was able to accomplish a "masking" effect simply by using 2D Transformations, meaning his solution is supported as far back as IE9.

Comment: The link is dead.